# SQL Update field Query error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I receive the following error message when trying to setup a simple query to update any '0's to '1's.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

```
SELECT *
FROM

UPDATE Table Policies_with_claims
SET Policies_with_claims.Claim_Count=1
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Sheenal_Policy_Data].[PolicyIdentifier], 
    COUNT([Sheenal_Claims_Data].[PolicyIdentifier]) AS Claim_Count
    FROM ( 
    [Medical Malpractice].[dbo].[Sheenal Policy Data] AS Sheenal_Policy_Data
    LEFT JOIN [Medical Malpractice].[dbo].[Sheenal Claims Data] AS Sheenal_Claims_Data ON
(Sheenal_Policy_Data.PolicyIdentifier = Sheenal_Claims_Data.PolicyIdentifier)
)
GROUP BY [Sheenal_Policy_Data].[PolicyIdentifier]
) AS Policies_with_Claims

WHERE Policies_with_claims.Claim_Count=0
```

Comment: Syntax is wrong at many places. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Build your queries systematically. You are wildly mixing parts of `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements. Make your subselect work first, then use it in the update and I have no clue what the initial `SELECT * FROM`  and following `WHERE` is doing in there.

Comment: The field Claim_Count has some values which are zero, I just want to change these to be one.

Comment: UPDATE Policies_with_claims
SET Policies_with_claims.Claim_Count='1'
WHERE Policies_with_claims.Claim_Count='0'

FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT [Sheenal_Policy_Data].[PolicyIdentifier], COUNT([Sheenal_Claims_Data].[PolicyIdentifier]) AS Claim_Count
FROM( 
[Medical Malpractice].[dbo].[Sheenal Policy Data] AS Sheenal_Policy_Data
LEFT JOIN [Medical Malpractice].[dbo].[Sheenal Claims Data] AS Sheenal_Claims_Data ON
(Sheenal_Policy_Data.PolicyIdentifier = Sheenal_Claims_Data.PolicyIdentifier)
)
GROUP BY [Sheenal_Policy_Data].[PolicyIdentifier]
) AS Policies_with_Claims